# Insert max value in a column to same column FAILS

Tags: mysql

I have a example table like **http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/31e65**

```
CREATE TABLE `t1`(
  `id` int(4) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(40),
  `signal` int(4),
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `id` (`id`),
  KEY `signal` (`signal`)
)ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

INSERT INTO `t1`
(`name`, `signal`)
VALUES
    ('a', 1),
    ('b', 2),
    ('c', 3),
    ('d', 4);
```

I try to insert new record to table `t1` with value in `signal` column is max value +1 in that column

Here is my code i'm using

```
Lock tables t1 write;
INSERT INTO `t1` 
(`name`, `signal`) 
VALUES
(SELECT MAX(signal)+1 FROM t1, 'e');
unlock t1;
```

But that's fails. How to do that thanks

Comment: Why is this tagged with PHP?

Comment: How does it fail?  Looks like it'd be a 1064 - syntax error

Comment: You're inserting `name` and `signal` but providing values for `signal` and `name`. Revers the order of your values.

Comment: @davidkonrad b/c i will using php to run the sql code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
INSERT INTO `t1` 
(`name`, `signal`)
SELECT
   'e', MAX(`signal`)+1 FROM t1
```

I think you had the order of the column reversed. I have changed it.

Comment: that's still fails :(

Comment: Running it in SqlFiddle, the difference is backticks surrounding the `signal` in MAX

Comment: why not using `values` tag?

Comment: This does not work for MySQL since it does not allow the same table in INSERT and SELECT subquery.